# Is Javascript/jQuery DOM creation safe until it's added to the document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, dom

**Please read this statement carefully:** let's assume before ANY elements are added to the `document` **all** unsafe elements in $dom have been removed. But they were initially created. Ok let's continue....

---

If a piece of user text is processed and can possiblity be loaded like so:

```
var comment = 'I\'m a naughty person!!' +
              '<script src="http://blah.com/some_naughty_javascript.js">';
var $dom = $('<div>' + comment + '</div>');
```

Is this **by itself** dangerous in any way? My point being, can just the simple act of creating a DOM somehow inject anything, or is it just simply processed and the structure is created?

**For example:**

```
var $dom = $('<script>alert("hi");</script>');
```

Obviously the message hi does not pop up until it's added to the `document`. But:

- Can any tag or anything created in this manner be dangerous?
- Can any functions in javascript/jquery "watch" for elements being created in this manner and act on it BEFORE it's been stripped of bad elements and put on document?

---

### Bounty Edit

So as outlined in the answers below, it seems this method isn't very safe, particularly for one reason:

- `var $dom = $('<img src="blah.jpg"/>')` -- this will request for the image straight away, regardless of if the object was added to the document.

This creates a major problem for dealing with HTML ajax requests. For example if we wanted to get the values from the inputs of the form:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'test.php',
  success: function(responseHTML) {
    var inputs = $(responseHTML).find('form input');
  }
});
```

This will involuntarily cause all images to be requested for by the browser.

**Bounty is awarded to anyone**:

- Who can provide a nice, safe way of dealing with ajax requests without the above issue.
- Ideally doesn't provide a regex answer... i.e. what if we wanted to do `$(responseHTML).find('img')` -- removing image tags with regex can't be an option, so an unobtrusive way would be needed to stop the src from loading, but still have the same attributes, structure, etc.

Comment: You are particularly paranoid aren't you? ;)

Comment: Why do you parse the HTML if you don't want to insert it? Why do you accept HTML from your users if you care for security?

Comment: @galambalazs see the bounty edit, this has all sorts of ramifications, such as parsing HTML ajax response i.e. what if you wanted to just insert selected divs, or images, you'll involuntarily invoke the browser to request for ALL image tags... this isn't good for performance. "use json" well sometimes this isn't an practical or an option.

Comment: @GaryGreen you are asking _your_ server for HTML. Why don't you sanitize the HTML on the server?

Comment: @Raynos, this is sometimes used not on my server, and I have no control over the pages, for example a Greasemonkey script.

Comment: @GaryGreen then use a server intermediate to request this external service on your behalf. I find it hard to find a legit use where you can't use an intermediate server and your also not just shooting yourself in the foot. As an academic excercise it's interesting, but there are probably better technical solutions to your actual problem.

Comment: @Raynos, since when do people code a Greasemonkey script to use a proxy server to parse ajax requests?! Listen, I appreciate your help but this is a question about utilising jQuery to parse *HTML* and not masking around the problem suggesting to *use any external proxies or intermediaries* are not a viable alternatives. I want to be able to ultilise jQuery to parse HTML responses without this downfall.

Comment: For example; I use a Greasemonkey jQuery-ajax bridge, and because of the higher browser privileges that Grasemonkey allows, I can request the source for any page. I want to get i.e. src for all images from a requested page. I could use regex to parse HTML, but apparently the world will crumble into the abyss and Margret Thatcher will raise from her grave, so to avoid all that I'd like to do `$(responseHTML).find('img').map(function() { return $(this).attr('src'); }).get();` without the browser requesting for EVERY SINGLE IMAGE on that page, which sometimes is a LOT.

Comment: @GaryGreen Yes you can't use regex, you need a real parser. There's an answer belong with a few links to parsers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is this by itself dangerous in any
>   way? My point being, can just the
>   simple act of creating a DOM somehow
>   inject anything, or is it just simply
>   processed and the structure is
>   created?

Simply creating an element *without* appending it to the dom will not cause any script to run since it is purely an object at this point (HtmlScriptElement).  When it is actually appended to the dom the script element will be evaluated and ran by the browser.  With that being said *I suppose* it is possible that an extremely crafty person could exploit a bug that is present in some framework or browser you might be using to cause an undesired outcome.

Consider this example:

```
<p>
    <input type="button" value="Store 'The Script' In Variable" id="store"/>
    <input type="button" value="Append 'The Script' To Dom" id="append"/>
</p>
<br/>
<p>
    <input type="button" value="Does nothing"/>
</p>
<h1>The Script</h1>
<pre id="script">
    $(function(){
        function clickIt(){
            $(this).clone().click(clickIt).appendTo("body");
        }
        $("input[type='button']").val("Now Does Something").click(clickIt);
    });
</pre>

var theScript;

$("#store").click(function() {
    theScript = document.createElement('script');
    var scriptText = document.createTextNode($("#script").text());
    theScript.appendChild(scriptText);
});

$("#append").click(function() {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    head.appendChild(theScript);
});
```

When you click on `store` it will create the HtmlScriptElement and store it into a variable.  You will notice that nothing is ran even though the object is created.  As soon as you click `append` the script is appended to the dom and immediately evaluated and the buttons do something different.

[**Code Example on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/TzGWe/1/)

> Can any functions in javascript/jquery "watch" for elements
>   being created in this manner and act
>   on it BEFORE it's been stripped of bad
>   elements and put on document?

jQuery *sort* of does that for you already as it does some internal script eval

*From [Karl Swedberg](http://api.jquery.com/append/#comment-67912032) post on `.append()`*

> All of jQuery's insertion methods use
>   a domManip function internally to
>   clean/process elements before and
>   after they are inserted into the DOM.
>   One of the things the domManip
>   function does is pull out any script
>   elements about to be inserted and run
>   them through an "evalScript routine"
>   rather than inject them with the rest
>   of the DOM fragment. It inserts the
>   scripts separately, evaluates them,
>   and then removes them from the DOM.
>   ...

You could alter the behavior of jQuery to remove all `<script/>` and sanitize other elements with inline javascript `onclick, mouseover, etc` when calling `append()` however that will only affect jQuery as someone could easily use vanilla javascript to append the `<script/>` element.

**Dom Mutation Events**

[Dom Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-MutationEvent) does defined some Dom mutation events to capture elements that are added to the dom one would look towards the event, [DOMNodeInserted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Events#Mutation_DOM_events). However it is fired after the element has already been added. ***note***, per Raynos these are currently [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents).

> DOMNodeInserted Fired when a node has
>   been added as a child of another node.
>   This event is dispatched after the
>   insertion has taken place. The target
>   of this event is the node being
>   inserted. Bubbles: Yes Cancelable: No
>   Context Info: relatedNode holds the
>   parent node

In the end it appears there is no totally stop a `<script/>` being appended to the dom via some other javascript. (at least not that I can find).

The best way I can suggest is to ***never ever trust user input as all user input is evil***. When you do dom manipulation double check to make sure there are no forbidden tags, be it `<script/>` or even plain `<p/>` elements and sanitize all input before it is persisted.

Also as John points out you need to worry about ***any*** element that can attach a `onclick` event or any inline javascript event handler.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting observations. So it seems it would be a safe-ish way of doing it, only if when you finally do `$dom.appendTo('body')` all script (and any other "bad" elements) are striped out. There doesn't seem to be any reliable way for a user to otherwise "force" the DOM to evaluate any code, because as you say, "they are simply instances of HTML Element." By the way -- "double check to make sure there are no invalid tags" -- there's no such thing as an "invalid" tag ;-) "<hello>" is just as valid as "<ul>"

Comment: @Gary, I adjusted to say forbidden tags or tags you don't deem safe and want stripped out. `:)`

Comment: @Mark DOM mutation events are currently deprecated and the spec is being re-written. So don't expect those to become standard in the near future.

Comment: @Gary: Don't forget that other tags can include javascript that would be run as well. For example, the user could insert *<a href="javascript:alert('breach your code'); return false;">Nasty link</a>*. If he did this and you let it be inserted into the DOM, there is another point where they can squeeze their own code into your page.

Comment: @Raynos, thanks for the information, updated the answer with the spec link that discusses that.  @John, didn't even think about that thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Have you guys tested things like `<img src="" />` I know that you can set `.src` on an `ImageElement` and the URL get's preloaded. You may be able to cause some damage through that somehow.

Comment: @Raynos Good point. I did some testing and it did indeed preload the image, simply doing: `$('<img src="http://www.google.co.uk/images/logos/ps_logo2.png"/>');` will get the image requested for, regardless of if you've added it to the `document` or not

Comment: @GaryGreen now can you sneak anything malicious into that url ? I can think of all kinds of bad images you can sneak into someone's computer.

Comment: I'm not sure about sneaking something bad into the url, not really my speciality ;-) can you think of anything? Also the simple fact that it loads any source automatically, without appending it to the DOM, is bad news altogether. I can see something like `src="huge_5_terabyte_file_here_please.jpg"`

Comment: @GaryGreen I was more thinking along the lines `src="child_porn_and_server_is_calling_police_right_now_we_have_your_IP.jpg"`

Comment: @Raynos @Gary, from this like it appears possible http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html `<IMG SRC="javascript:alert('XSS');">` could be a problem with IE6 and such, but modern browsers will not `eval()` the js. (

Answer (score 8):

### An obligatory response to your first example

```
var comment = 'I\'m a naughty person!!' +
              '<script src="http://blah.com/some_naughty_javascript.js">';
var $dom = $('<div>' + comment + '</div>');
```

Don’t do this. Instead, you should use an API which treats text as text and doesn’t expose you to injection at all. In this example, you should do this:

```
var $dom = $('<div>').text(comment);
```

…which creates a `div`, *then* sets its text content. `comment` is never parsed as HTML, so there is no chance that the browser will ever do anything dangerous with it.

### Moving on to the question

If I understand you correctly, you’d like to parse information out of arbitrary HTML, without the browser getting ready to display it (say, by loading images).

**This is tricky**, because the DOMs built into web browsers are built to deal with content which will, at some point, be displayed. jQuery (and any library that creates DOM nodes) is limited by this.

DOM Level 2 [defines an API to create documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/CR-DOM-Level-2-20000510/html.html#HTML-DOM-createHTMLDocument) which are completely separate from the active one: `document.implementation.createHTMLDocument(title)`. In my testing, nothing is loaded when an `img` is created on one of these documents:

```
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument(''),
    img = doc.createElement('img');
img.src = 'http://example.com/image.jpg'; // Nothing happens.
// Alternatively…
doc.body.innerHTML = '<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg">'; // Nope.
```

So, a document created this way appears to be a nice sandbox to parse and explore HTML. You can even create a jQuery wrapper around nodes in a different document (`$(doc.body)`), and explore it through jQuery APIs. When you find the nodes you’re looking for, you can convert them back to HTML for insertion into the active document, or use [methods like `importNode()` and `adoptNode()`](http://www.w3.org/DOM/faq.html#ownerdoc) to transfer them directly into the active document.

Unfortunately, support for all of this is new. Firefox supports `createHTMLDocument` in version 4 and up (a similar `createDocument` method, which deals with XML, is [available in older versions](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t122)), and Internet Explorer supports it [in version 9 and up](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t12). Also, as far as I can tell, the spec *does not guarantee* that images and scripts won’t be preloaded on these documents.

**A better solution is to avoid the browser’s HTML parser**. A number of JavaScript HTML 
parsers have shown up lately. The simplest is probably John Resig’s [Pure JavaScript HTML Parser](http://ejohn.org/blog/pure-javascript-html-parser/). You can feed it HTML, and it triggers callbacks when it hits new tags, attributes, and text. From these callbacks, you can create new HTML, build DOM nodes or store the document in whatever form you like — and you can ignore attributes and nodes that you consider dangerous.

You can find an example of this [in Dan Kaminsky’s Interpolique](http://dankaminsky.com/interpolique/), a proof-of-concept which aimed to kill XSS and SQL injection once and for all. The project hasn’t taken off, but if you download Interpolique, you’ll find a `safeParse()` function stuck at the bottom of htmlparser.js, which uses a whitelist of tag names and attributes, and throws away everything else.

[jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) is a complete (up to DOM Level 2, with some Level 3) HTML DOM written in JavaScript — you could use it to work with HTML safely. You can even load up its own copy of jQuery. However, it’s written for CommonJS, without browser compatibility in mind. I don’t know if it will work in most web browsers without modification. It’s also a big library.

**If at all possible, the ideal solution is to serve AJAX responses in a format other than HTML.** Do you need to include the extra, unsafe HTML at all? If you do the work on the server of returning only what you’ll need…

```
{
    "inputs": [
        '<input …>',
        '<input …>'
    ],
}
```

…your job on the client side becomes much easier.

Comment: Interesting, `createHTMLDocument` looks promising, if it weren't for limited support. The HTML parsers are good suggestions, although are a bit heavy as I supose a simple regex could remove the src from the image, and push that data onto the elements property i.e. `src2` so it's still usable. I guess I was hoping for a magic property that stopped this preloading behaviour, looks like a more dirty fix is needed. Also, sometimes serving in another format isn't possible, i.e. for use in a Greasemonkey script.

Answer (score 2):

Excellent question. It appears it is possible to inject script and place event handlers inside it. I've tested using the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            <!-- 
            $(function() {
                var $dom = $('<script>$(".testbutton").live("click", function() { alert("hi") });</script>');

                $(".firstbutton").click(function() {
                    $("BODY").append($dom);
                });
            });
            -->
        </script>
    </head>

    <body style="padding:0">            
        <button class="firstbutton">Click this first</button>

        <button class="testbutton">Then this</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can see that the second button has no effect until the first button has been clicked and the script tag added to the DOM.

This could possibly be open to abuse if user form input is taken and dynamically inserted into the page. In which case data sanitisation should definately be used.

This is something I'd never thought of - thanks for raising it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  The question asks: if you *don't* insert the element into the page, is it safe?  Your answer says: if you *do* insert the element into the page, it is unsafe (but that's not what was being asked, and this fact is already stated in the question).

Comment: @D.W. True, however this is an answer to the original question, before it went through a multitude of edits and a bounty addition ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the script will not work as long as it is not appended to DOM.

```
$(function ()
{
    var ss = document.createElement('script');
    var scr = 'alert("bah");';
    var tt = document.createTextNode(scr);
    ss.appendChild(tt);
    var hh = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    //hh.appendChild(ss);
});
```

And

```
$(function ()
{
    var ss = document.createElement('script');
    var scr = 'alert("bah");';
    var tt = document.createTextNode(scr);
    ss.appendChild(tt);
    var hh = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    hh.appendChild(ss);
});
```