# Struggling with how to turn a normal PHP form into a form that submits using JQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have been reading lots of articles and also questions here on SO but I am still confused how to implement the functionality into my own work and would much appreciate some helpful pointers.

What I have already is a page with two separate forms - one is a simple search with some drop-down menus and text box inputs - I think this one should be a lot easier to implement.

The advanced search form includes the simple search values by copying anything in the simple search fields into some hidden inputs. This form is also based around a row of three dropdowns that is cloned and removed at the users will to allow for any number of inputs to be searched for.

The main confusion I have is my forms action point to the same page where I have all of my php code to take the values and construct a MySQL query etc so I don't know how to use the `success` part of the AJAX request.

The complete code for the page, should you wish to see it, is [here](http://pastebin.com/eTPUnGMq)

A Fiddle showing the advanced search is here: [Advanced Seach Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ubTe/80/)

So bascially, what I am looking to try and find out is how to turn a static form that works perfectly into one that submits with JQuery and shows a nice 'searching' preloader etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll, you've certainly done the hard work here ;-) the jQuery side of it is fairly straight forward. You query your server with the serialized form data. Something to get you on the right track:

```
$form = $('.advancedsearchform');

$form.submit(function() {

    $.ajax($form.attr('action'), {
      data: $form.serialize(),
      dataType: 'JSON',
      type: 'post', 

          beforeSend: function() {
            var $load = $('#loadingmessage');
            if (!$load.length)
            {
                $load = $('<div id="loadingmessage">').appendTo($form);
            }
            $load.html('Loading... Please wait...');
        },

        success: function(response) {
            // response is the text sent back by server
            // maybe you could use json_encode in PHP with a success message?
        },

        complete: function() {
            // Hide loading message:
            $('#loadingmessage').hide();
        }
    });

      return false; // Cancel default event
});
```

Comment: wow, thanks Gary, I'll certainly give it a bash - still don't know what to do about the success message but if it's ok I'll post back here my failures....

Comment: Your success message is basically sent by the server, usually in JSON format, and will contain the result of your query i.e. your search results. For example the literal text sent back will be: `{ 'html': '<div>result1</div><div>result2</div>', 'result': 'success' }` then you can read in your success function these values like a simple javascript object: `response.html` or `response.result` -- remember to set `dataType` to 'json' so the JSON response is convereted to a javascript object.

Comment: Your other option is to send the response in a more complex JSON format such as `[ { 'author': 'Gary Green', 'book': 'Best coding practises' }, { 'author': 'Martin', 'book': 'Star wars!' } ]` -- although this involves you process the result into HTML. It's finding that balance between holding your HTML structure on the server side/javascript.

Comment: hmm. So far I've took the action property out of my advanced search form and not really done anything else apart from add in `dataType: 'json',`. I put your code inside the `$(document).ready(function() {` is that ok? The form is still submitting statically and the loadingmessage div doesn't show.

Don't want to sound st00pid but I still don't understand what to do with the success message or what to do with it - e.g. pass it to the function that gets the POST variables and then that calls the function to build the query etc.

Comment: just another update/question! I now have this `url: 'testdocs-db.php',
            cache: 'false',
            type: 'post', 
            dataType: 'json',` but shouldn't there be a `data` parameter in there aswell - just wondering how to do this as the `$form.serialize()` line you wrote should do the same thing?

Comment: Ah. no probs, thanks for that. That seems to be doing everything but for my arch nemesis - success! I need to do something but don't know what. I added in `url: 'testdocs-db.php',` but not sure if that's required here? If everything else is working I would have thought that the code that gets all the `$_POST` variables would do it's magic but apparently not? The only other thing is that I think the `$('#loadingmessage').hide();` is hiding the entire div when the whole process is complete which is quite strange, I thought it might be because of the `append` but it still shouldn't do that?

Comment: You should be receiving the post values in testdocs-db.php -- once you've done all your processing, put the result HTML into a variable i.e. `$json['html'] = 'blah<br/>your search result html';` then just echo this via `echo json_encode($json)`. jQuery will receive it in the success function and convert it to a javascript object. As a test, try echoing this: `echo '{ "test": "hello!" }';` in your PHP file, then in the success function: `success: function(response) { alert(response.test); }`

Comment: ok, I will have a play around and see if I can figure it out. Managed to sort the hiding thing so only one more step and it's done!

Comment: I put in the `echo` after the check to see if the `advancedsearchsubmit` was set but nothing is displayed. One thing I noticed in Firebug is that the `type` seems to be set to `GET` despite it being explicitly set to `POST`?

Comment: Strange. Is it even sending the correct POST/GET values and to the right page?

Comment: I don't see the parameters when looking in firebug, I did before when it was trying to use `GET` and when it wasn't quite working as it is just now but I don't know if it's possible to see the parameters anywhere if it's actually using `POST`? Obvously it's easier with `GET` as they appear in the url. Just found it strange why the type shows as `GET` when `POST` is specified in the form and the ajax request.

Comment: Have you tested it in Firefox? Can you do a screenshot?

Comment: Morning Gary, yes I will grab a screenshot just now

Comment: screenshot ahoy: http://img846.imageshack.us/i/screenshotva.png/

Hmm, this one is easier to see: http://img35.imageshack.us/i/screenshotfpo.png/

Comment: Thanks for that. Would you be able to enable the Net tab and see the actual POST/GET request sent by the browser. It should also show it's values sent. Then just pastebin the result or another screenshot.

Comment: Hi, here is a screenshot of the POST header, forgot to crop it to cut out my second monitor though! http://img8.imageshack.us/i/screenshotqlh.png/

Comment: So it is doing a POST request and submitting the correct values afterall. What does the response tab show?

Comment: Obviously what's happening is it's outputting the HTML page contents. You need to output JUST the json string object as per my comments above. It's possible jquery is seeing that the response is clearly not a json object therefore it's not calling the success function. By the way your code in testdocs-db is a complete mess. The easier thing to would be to forget about returning result in JSON format and just 1. Send the POST with serialized data, 2. In the success function select the DIV (or whatever the results are contained in) and add that to the DOM

Comment: i.e. `success: function(response) { $(response).find('#search_results').appendTo('body'); }` where the #search_results is the results i.e. DIV container from the ajax response (we need to get just this DIV as your post response returns the WHOLE page). You can change .appendTo to put the search results anywhere you like, for example: `.insertAfter($form)` -- remember to change the `dataType` to `html`

Comment: Thanks a bunch, got it working and I really appreciate your help. Just one question - the search results come up but I am using a JQuery plugin called dataTables to show them and it has been debunked somehow. I thought it might be to do with only returning the one div from the response but all the includes are already done on the page so not sure why it breaks

Comment: One thing to watch out for with using `$(response)` is it'll download any src, for images, etc. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594254/is-javascript-jquery-dom-creation-safe-until-its-added-to-the-document --- I'm unfamiliar with the dataTables plugin, though I assume you'll need to re-initialise the dataTables plugin in the `success` (maybe because it doesn't act on a .live event? not sure)

Comment: ah, got it re-initialised, thanks again. Only problem I'm having now is the thumbnails in the thumbnail column have somehow pushed themselves over further to the right and if I do another advanced search the `loadingmessage` div doesn't show and and a new set of results is appended above the original search - I actually don't mind this though.

Comment: For the loading, I would use something like this (just created it) http://jsfiddle.net/wK9f9/ -- to replace the old search results you can do; `success: function() { $('#search_results').remove(); //... rest of your code here`

Comment: Cool Fiddle. Sorted the search result stacking up, only thing I need to fix is the loading animation not showing for all submits after the first

Comment: You need to $load.show() in the `beforeSend` as the loading div isn't re-created everytime. After you've faded it out using `.fadeOut()` it becomes hidden, hence the need to `.show()` it

Comment: ah, I had the right thing but in the wrong place. Thanks again for all your help, superb.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to proceed here:

1. Split page rendering and search processing code. Search processing code should return search results in a particular format (HTML, XML, JSON). After getting search results you can display them in whatever way you need.
2. Keep your code as it is and parse data returned by AJAX call to extract search results section from it. If you go this way AJAX call will return full page as a result. So using jQuery's `find` method you will need to extract search results section from it.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: To be honest, I'm still perplexed as to what steps to take!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). It's a dead simple way to AJAXify an existing form.

Comment: Thanks, I have actually already looked at that plugin but one thing I'm unsure of is whether this will work if I put the action of the forms as the same page that is submitting them?